# get profile picture from instagram api

Tags: json, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to get profile pictures using Instagram Api. I tried the following code:

```
function getpho($userid)
{
    $userid = "000000"; 
    $token = "my access token";
    $url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/".$userid."/?access_token=".$token;
    $get = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($get);

    foreach($json->data as $user)
    {
            return $user->profile_picture;
    }
}

echo getpho($userid);
```

But this returns a blank page. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$json = json_decode($get);
return $json->data->profile_picture;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're in Sandbox mode.
In this mode you can get media only of users that you've invited (up to 10). They will doesn't receive a notification, but they shall accept the request at this address: https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/sandbox_invites/

Answer (score 0):

By using this link you can get insta user details :
https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1&__d=dis